# Batch file to copy content of one txt file into another text file

Tags: batch-file

I have two text files:

1. header file `header.text` has text:

> ```
> *===================================================
> *          HEADER     : bulk                            
> *===================================================
> * New|New|ON|CRM|Pre
> *===================================================
> ```

2. body file `body.text` has text:

> ```
> 0999|Siebel|Customer5|12345|SA|Cash|test|||||||0|
> ```

Need to copy the header file text to body file text and after copying it should look like below:

> ```
> *===================================================
> *          HEADER     : bulk                            
> *===================================================
> * New|New|ON|CRM|Pre
> *===================================================
> 0999|Siebel|Customer5|12345|SA|Cash|test|||||||0|
> ```

Need batch script to implement this.

Comment: What was stopping you from reading the help for the copy command and at least attempting to figure it out on your own?

Answer (score 1):

You can append two files using the '+' operator like so...

```
copy /b header.txt + body.txt destfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

just append...

```
type body.text>>header.text
```